# What do I actually need in a C++ project?

Tags: c++, ide, project

I have been programming a lot in college and have a basic understanding on how to program. All the time the programming environment was configured and all necessary files were provided. Even the source files were pre-filled, where I had to only add essential lines of code. Thus, I learned the programming language and how to code, but I have no idea what is necessary besides the code to make a working application.

Now, when I want to make my own application, what is necessary to have except the functional programming code? What files are created automatically for me (such as in MS Visual Studio 2008 C++), what other files/libraries should be included by me? What are the essential project settings i should pay attention to? etc.

Most of the tutorials I found cover programming essentials and rarely mention the questions above. If someone could name the topics that cover these questions, I would greatly appreciate. The links to educational sources would be welcome.

Comment: Once you've chosen a programming environment - such as *(the mentioned)* Visual Studio 2008 - that environment's website would [teach you the fundamentals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384847.aspx) of starting a project.  And when something specific evades you, those questions are very welcomed here.  Have you tried creating your own application yet?

Comment: This if off topic, but you should look into [what GNU make is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) and how it works, and take a look at [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264249/how-does-the-compilation-linking-process-work). This is the basic process behind the scenes in most development environments ... for the most part.

Comment: @DrewDormann, Steve:  I am on it!

Comment: My advice **throw away the IDE** (for now). Spend some time working from the command line and using a text editor.  Start by making build scripts then progress to building simple Makefiles. Then consider going back to an IDE.